# What is naming convention of Tiles generated in GeoServer?

Tags: geoserver, tiles, geowebcache

While the requests to the tiles from the client are in the format {x}/{y}/{z}, the tiles are not named in the same fashion in the file system. The folder names also look different.

What is the naming convention followed by GeoServer while creating the tiles?

Comment: Please post example file and directory names of what you got.

Comment: As far as I know the way how the tiles are named is not documented. I would try to find the logic from the source code of GeoWebCache. This could be the place to start https://github.com/GeoWebCache/geowebcache/tree/master/geowebcache/core/src/main/java/org/geowebcache/storage/blobstore/file

Comment: I came across this thread a long time ago. May be it will be a help. https://sourceforge.net/p/geowebcache/mailman/geowebcache-users/thread/28819540.post%40talk.nabble.com/#msg25474083

Answer (score 2):

If you look under `new Blobstore` you will see there are three options:

[image]

- GeoWebCache default
- TMS layout
- Slippy

If you intend to interact with the tiles in any way what so ever chose one of the last two so that you are working with a clearly documented layout. Don't ever try to use GeoWebCache default as that is an internal layout that may change in the future if the developers decide to make a change (for improved efficiency, or just because they want to) there is a reason that it is opaque and not documented.